# sort x-axis values in matplotlib histogram from lowest to highest value using python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, data-visualization

At the moment I have a script which renders the following histogram:

[image]

Based on this data:

```
{"first":"A","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"B","second":"1","third":"2"} 
{"first":"C","second":"2","third":"2"} 
{"first":"D","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"E","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"F","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"G","second":"3","third":"2"} 
{"first":"H","second":"4","third":"2"} 
{"first":"I","second":"4","third":"2"} 
{"first":"J","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"K","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"L","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"M","second":"0","third":"2"} 
{"first":"N","second":"0","third":"2"}
```

This is the code that renders the data for the histogram:

```
with open('toy_two.json', 'rb') as inpt:

    dict_hash_gas = list()
    for line in inpt:
        resource = json.loads(line)
        dict_hash_gas.append({resource['first']:resource['second']})

# Count up the values
counts = collections.Counter(v for d in dict_hash_gas for v in d.values())

counts = counts.most_common()

# Apply a threshold
threshold = 4275
counts = [list(group) for val, group in itertools.groupby(counts, lambda x: x[1] > threshold) if val]

print(counts)
```

It's being plotted like this:

```
# Transpose the data to get the x and y values
labels, values = zip(*counts[0])

indexes = np.arange(len(labels))
width = 1

plt.bar(indexes, values, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, labels)
plt.show()
```

The question is, how to reorganize the x-axis so that they're order from lowest to highest, i.e.

```
0, 1, 3, 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since you are already using `matplotlib`, it makes better sense to do the data wrangling in `pandas` as well.

```
In [101]: JSON = '''[{"first":"A","second":"1","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"B","second":"1","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"C","second":"2","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"D","second":"3","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"E","second":"3","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"F","second":"3","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"G","second":"3","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"H","second":"4","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"I","second":"4","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"J","second":"0","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"K","second":"0","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"L","second":"0","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"M","second":"0","third":"2"}, 
   .....: {"first":"N","second":"0","third":"2"}]
   .....: '''

In [102]: df = pd.read_json(JSON)

In [103]: df
Out[103]: 
   first  second  third
0      A       1      2
1      B       1      2
2      C       2      2
3      D       3      2
4      E       3      2
5      F       3      2
6      G       3      2
7      H       4      2
8      I       4      2
9      J       0      2
10     K       0      2
11     L       0      2
12     M       0      2
13     N       0      2

In [104]: df.groupby('second').size().plot(kind='bar')
Out[104]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1104eac10>
```

[image]

The bar graph put your category in the right order.

But if you just need a general method to put your bars in order, you might just construct a temporary dataframe, sort it, and then plot:

```
In [109]: pd.DataFrame({'Labels': labels, 
                        'Values': values}).sort_values(['Labels']).plot(kind='bar',
                                  x='Labels',
                                  y='Values',
                                  width=1.0)
```

[image]

Comment: but on the real dataset the preprocessing is important- because it's much larger and more complicated than the toy example, and so- afterwards it's no longer in JSON format. Is there some way to achieve this with the data after it's passed through that preproessing pipeline?

Comment: In that case you might consider building a temporary dataframe, sort by labels and then plot.  See edit.